# Raise exception and in upper method call except

Tags: python-3.x

I have been working with with exceptions where im trying to still improve on how to raise correctly. I have done something like this

**main.py**

```py
from lib.utils import ExceptionCounter

class BarryException():
    pass
    
candy = "hello"
color = "world"

try:
    test = type(int("string"))
except Exception as err:

    # My own counter for exception that sends to discord if allowed_count is 0 by calling discord.notify(msg)
    ExceptionCounter().check(
        exception=BarryException,
        allowed_count=0,
        msg={
            'Title': 'Unexpected Error',
            'Reason': str(err),
            'Payload': str({"candy": candy, "color": color})
        }
    )
```

**lib.utils**

```
class ExceptionCounter:
    """
    Counter to check if we get exceptions x times in a row.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.exception_count = {}

    def check(self, exception, msg, allowed_count):
        exception_name = exception.__name__

        # the dict.get() method will return the value from a dict if exists, else it will return the value provided
        self.exception_count[exception_name] = self.exception_count.get(exception_name, 0) + 1

        if self.exception_count[exception_name] >= allowed_count:
            Discord_notify(msg)
            raise exception(msg)

    def reset(self):
        self.exception_count.clear()
```

**However Someone from Code Review recommended me to do this instead:**

Raise with contextual data in a custom exception type:

```py
try:
    ...
except Exception as e:
    raise BarryException('Unexpected error testing', candy=candy, color=color) from e
```

Don't call Discord from there; don't do exception counting there; don't form a discord message payload dictionary there - just raise. In an upper method, you can except and do the Discord notification.

ExceptionCounter should not know about Discord at all, and should be strictly constrained to exception count limits and re-raising.

---

My problem is that I dont quite understand the part *just raise. In an upper method, you can except and do the Discord notification.* - I would appreciate if someone could explain or even show me a example of what it actually means :(

Comment: Their point is that when you do `allowed_count=0`, you don't actually need to use `ExceptionCounter`. You can just reraise the exception. His other point is that the error reporting to discord shouldn't happen inside `ExceptionCounter`, but somewhere else futher up the call stack (were you would normally catch the exception thrown in `ExceptionCounter`).

Comment: @MegaIng Make sense to not call it there yes, but where in that case would I need to do it? Like maybe outside the class of `ExceptionCounter` ?

Comment: @Megalng Something like this: ```Discord_Notification()  raise BarryException('Unexpected error testing', candy=candy, color=color) from e```

Comment: Idk, I do not have a good overview of the code. This is not really a good SO question. It might be better to ask a more precises question on CR, and/or maybe wait for the original answer to respond.

Comment: @MegaIng you can see it from here if that would help :) Myself im having super hard time to actually understand the exception part. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/259561/check-if-new-dict-values-has-been-added/259622?noredirect=1#comment512192_259622